# NZEC error in JAVA.Checked all possible ones but couldnt find the glitch

Tags: java

The following Java code is throwing an NZEC runtime error when I attempt to run it.  I have checked through all of it, and I am unable to locate where the error could be taking place.  The formatted code can also  be found [here](http://pastebin.com/E6sFwT60):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Quad implements Comparable {
    int x,y;
    public Quad(int i,int j) {
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }
    int dist = y-x;
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Quad q;
        q = (Quad) obj;
        if((Integer) (this.x) == (Integer) (q.x)) {
            if(this.dist>q.dist)
                return -1;
        }
        if(this.x<q.x)
            return -1;
        return 1;
    }
}
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t --> 0) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            Quad[] q = new Quad[n];
            for(int i = 0;i < n; i++) {
                int u = sc.nextInt();
                int v = sc.nextInt();
                q[i] = new Quad(u,v);
            } Arrays.sort(q);
            int max = q[0].y, k=0;
            for(int i = 0;i < n - 1;i++) {
                if(q[k].x == q[i+1].x) {
                    if(max < q[i+1].y) {
                        q[k].y = q[k].y^q[i + 1].y;
                        q[i + 1].y=q[k].y^q[i + 1].y;
                        q[k].y=q[k].y^q[i+1].y;
                        max = q[k].y;
                    }
                } else {
                    k = i+1;
                    max = q[k].y;
                }
            }
            //for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            // out.print(q[i].x +" ");
            // out.println(q[i].y);
            //}
            int count = 1, flag = 0;
            int y1 = q[0].y;
            for(int i = 0;i < n - 1;i++) {
                if(y1 - q[i+1].x<0) {
                    count++;
                    y1 = q[i + 1].y;
                    flag = 1;
                }
                if(q[i].x == q[i + 1].x && y1-q[i + 1].y < 0 && flag == 0) {
                    y1 = q[i+1].y;
                    continue;
                }
                //if(y1-q[i+1].x>0&&flag == 0&&q[i].x!=q[i+1].x&&){
                // y1 = q[i+1].y;
                //} } System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code... this is unreadable.

Comment: Copy your original code into the question, highlight it all, press `ctrl` + `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program ran fine for me. Here is an example of my input:

```
2
3
1 2
3 4
5 6
2
1 2
3 4
```

In Java, several Exceptions including NumberFormatException, division by zero, and ArrayIndexOutOfBounds can cause an NZEC error. So maybe you were inputting your numbers incorrectly.

Comment: Its the same input format as you have taken.It didn't run for this particular problem http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/ONEKING.

Comment: I tried it out. It's not getting any runtime errors. Make sure you're hitting enter after each line and that there is a space in between the two numbers that are on the same line.